# Lost value in directive angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive, something like that:

```
.directive('reasonField', ['questionApiService', function(questionApiService) {
 var id = 1;
 return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
        console.log(scope.data);
    });
    }
 };
}]);
```

When i see the console print, shows something like that:

```
{ "arrayFieldsDisplay": [ 1 ], "jsonField": { "listQ": [ 1 ], "answQ": {}, "nextQ": 1 }, "yearStart": 1925, "yearEnd": 1997 }
```

If i try to do console.log(scope.data.yearStart), the console returns the value correctly, but if i try to print console.log(scope.data.jsonField) doesn't return nothing.

I don't understand what is wrong.

Thank u in advance.

**Edit 1**

The controller logic is:

Father controller (name file: question.js)

```
.controller('QuestionIndexController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.productTypeUrl = $routeParams.stringUrl;
    $scope.data.arrayFieldsDisplay = [];
    $scope.question_array = {};
})
```

Son controller (name file: question.js):

```
.controller('QuestionFormController', ['$scope', '$location', 'questionApiService', function($scope, $location, questionApiService ){
    var d = new Date();
    $scope.data.jsonField = {};
    $scope.data.yearStart = d.getFullYear() - 90;
    $scope.data.yearEnd = d.getFullYear() - 18;

    questionApiService.getField()
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.data.jsonField = response.data;
            $scope.data.arrayFieldsDisplay.push($scope.data.jsonField['nextQ']);
        });
```

Son directive (in other file):

```
.directive('reasonField', ['questionApiService', function(questionApiService) {
    var id = 1;
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
                //alert(scope.data.yearStart);
```

I guess, if i set into "questionApiService.getField()" my variable "$scope.data.jsonField" the value must keeping in the scope for use it in mi directive. My logic is wrong?

Comment: What happens when you log the other properties of data?

Comment: Hi @camden_kid. I'm checking, and the value for "arrayFieldsDisplay", doesnt's display. The set of that values is in previus controller.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what the solution to your problem is. Good luck!

Comment: Don't worry, thank u anyway.